# Проблема запуска ungit на linux (error: Can't run "git --version". Is git installed and available in your path?)

Tags: git

После установки nodejs npm и git не запускается [ungit](https://github.com/FredrikNoren/ungit).

Все ошибки, которые выдаёт система, сводятся к неправильному пути. Поиск выдаёт только ошибки под винду.

[image: сама ошибка в терминале]

Comment: Вместо скриншотов вставляйте код, пожалуйста. Скриншоты не индексируются поисковиками и это сильно снижает шансы, что кто-нибудь потом найдёт этот вопрос.

Comment: По вопросу: если в консоли выполнить `git --version`, какой результат?

Comment: git version 2.1.4

Comment: может ли быть так, что ungit запускается в другом окружении или от другого пользователя? Кстати, а что показывает `which git`? Может быть, абсолютный путь к git захардкодили в ungit.

Comment: ➜  ~ which git
/usr/bin/git